# Mongodb aggregation Count fields which are grouped

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got the following query::

```
db.collection.aggregate({'$group':{
  '_id': "$city"
}})
```

which give the following results:

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "city1"

    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "city2"

    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "city3"

    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "city4"

    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

There are four grouped cities, how can I calculate number of fields which are grouped?
Like this:

```
"result" : [ 
    {
        "count_grouped_fields" : 4

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `$group` pipeline:

`{$group:{'_id': "city_count", count : { $sum : 1 }}}`

Or use the distinct command (no aggregation) :

`db.collection.distinct("city")`